# Castle Windsor: conditional component registration when scanning an assembly

Tags: castle-windsor

Am using Castle Windsor to register multiple components that share one common interface at the top chain, using the following:

```
container.Register(
    Types.FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.MyAssembly")
        .BasedOn<IService>()
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient())
)
```

Among all the components inside MyAssembly, I have the following:

```
public interface IHandler : IService
public class MessageHandler : IHandler
public class CachedMessageHandler : IHandler
```

During the registration above, is there a way to pick one of the two components (MessageHandler or CachedMessageHandler) based on some conditional value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

```
.BasedOn<IService>()
```

is shorthand for

```
.Pick().If(t => typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

Knowing that, you have the possibility to do powerful things. Just to give you an idea what you can do:

1.
Possibly this is what you wanted. Pick one of the two components based on some conditional value:

```
var shouldUseCache = true; //get this from configuration

//later in container.Register
.Pick().If(t =>
{
    if (shouldUseCache)
    {
        return typeof (IService).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof (CachedMessageHandler) == t;
    }
    return typeof (IService).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof (MessageHandler) == t;
})
```

Be warned though:

- once the component is registered, it will be hard/impossible/antipattern to remove that registration from the container
- if you make "conditional registration", it may be tricky for developers to debug injections later. Depending on your situation you may want to create **HandlerProvider** which will have explicit methods like: **.GetCached** or **.GetTransient**

2.
You can select all types which implement **IService** but exclude those which also implement **IHandler**:

```
.Pick().If(t => typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && !typeof(IHandler).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

3.
You can do naming conventions, for example only register all types which implement **IHandler** and ends with **SuperHandler**:

```
.Pick().If(t => typeof(IHandler).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && t.Name.EndsWith("SuperHandler"))
```